# Multi check Calculated Field formula

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Looking for some assistance with a sharepoint calculated field formula...

Four Fields
f01-a
f01-b
f01-c
f01-d

If f01-a=Yes & f02-b=Yes & f01-c=No
If f01-a=Yes & f02-b=Yes & f01-c=Yes & f01-d=No

in both cases field should be set to Yes if neither combination is true then field is No

Answer (score 1):

If this is for Choice columns with the "checkboxes" option enabled, then those columns are not supported by SharePoint Calculated Columns. You could add a workflow that takes the data from the Choice checkboxes and updates the result column using logic in the workflow.

If this is for multiple Yes/No columns, then this may be what you are looking for:

```
=IF( 
    OR(
       AND( [f01-a], [f02-b], NOT( [f01-c]) ),
       AND( [f01-a], [f02-b], [f01-c], NOT( [f01-d]) )
      )
    , true
    , false
   )
```

It can be shortened to:

```
=OR(
    AND( [f01-a], [f02-b], NOT( [f01-c]) ),
    AND( [f01-a], [f02-b], [f01-c], NOT( [f01-d]) )
   )
```

Comment: tried this and got the classic something went wrong

=IF(OR(AND([f01-a],[f02-b],NOT([f01-c])),AND([f01-a],[f02-b],[f01-c],NOT(]f01-d]))),”Yes”,”No”)

Comment: There was one backward square bracket! (fixed in the Answer) By the way, did you intend the "b" item to be "f02" while the rest are "f01"?  Also, remember this only works for simple Yes/No column types and not multiple-choice Choice columns.